# Reexpanding Variables in Makefile after Launch

Tags: makefile

I have the following simple makefile to create documentation by converting markdown to HTML.  A script named `make_bookshelves.py` creates several markdown files and then all the markdown files need to be converted to HTML.

The problem is that the `MD_FILES` variable gets set to the existing list of markdown files **before** the `make_bookshelves.py` script has run.  So those markdown files never make it into `MD_FILES` variable and thus never make it into the `HTML_FILES` variable and thus are ignored.

If I run `make` twice I get all my files because all the markdown files exist at the start of the make run.

Is there a way to get Make to reevaluate the `MD_FILES` and `HTML_FILES` variables after `make_bookshelves.py` has been run.

I've tried recursively invoking `make` but this doesn't solve the problem because the variables have already been set.

```
# $Id: Makefile 12980 2017-09-21 18:49:42Z nrp0238769 $

# A simple Makefile to build the UTE documentation from source

MD_FILES := $(shell find src -name '*.md')
HTML_FILES := $(addprefix html/,$(notdir $(MD_FILES:.md=.html)))

make_docs: src/bookshelves/bookshelf.md $(HTML_FILES)

html/%.html : %.md
    md2html.py $<  $@ --style-sheet=../css/mcs.css

src/bookshelves/bookshelf.md:
         ./make_bookshelves.py src
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I took the trouble to write this up, I thought I'd share the answer.  Writing up the problem showed me the answer.

The problem was the use of the `:=` assignment.  This caused the `MD_FILES` and `HTML_FILES` to be set only if they haven't been passed.  The solution is this:

```
MD_FILES = $(shell find src -name '*.md')
HTML_FILES = $(addprefix html/,$(notdir $(MD_FILES:.md=.html)))
```

And

```
make_docs: src/bookshelves/bookshelf.md 
    $(MAKE) $(HTML_FILES)
```

Now `MD_FILES` and `HTML_FILES` get reevaluated after `make_bookshelves.py` has been run.